# Show all processes in an AnyCPU application

Tags: c#, process, 32bit-64bit

I am writing an application for any CPU. When I am running the following on a 64bit-PC it will not work:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] running = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i < running.Length; i++){
    try{
        Console.WriteLine(running[i].MainModule.FileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

It only shows the 32bit-processes in the array running because it is running in the 32bit-mode. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I find this very hard to believe

Comment: `GetProcesses` even returns 64 bit processes on my machine when run in x86 (rather than Any CPU). So There's got to be something else going on.

Comment: How does for example task manager do it? It shoes 32bit and 64bit processes one list. Maybe I will write a second program (64bit) which helps me killing the process.

Comment: This works here just fine. Windows Vista 64 Business - made a small C# that just does this, and in debugger it shows 32-bit and 64-bit cpus. Also made 32-bit and 64-bit version of it - still works (VS2008, .NET 2.0)

Comment: No matter what configuration I choose, only 32 bit processes are displayed (only ones with the star * behind their names in task manager).

Comment: @birk this works fine, the problem must be in your code

Comment: This is my code:

   System.Diagnostics.Process[] running = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
            for (int i = 0; i < running.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(running[i].MainModule.FileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);

Comment: put that code in the question!

Comment: I got the answer:

    running[i].MainModule.FileName
is not supported by 64-bit processes. This was the reason my code always threw an exception. So the 64bit-processes were not listed.

Comment: @Brik: plop that in an answer and we can +1 and you can accept it (in 24 hours)!

Comment: that will teach you not to swallow exceptions! ;-)

Comment: I can plop that in an answer in about 7 hours. @Dave: Yes, but I did not know what the error caused.

Comment: Now my question is: How to get the file name of all processes in the list? running[i].MainModule.FileName only works for 32bit-processes.

Comment: Use System.Management, Win32_Process WMI class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
running[i].MainModule.FileName
```

is not supported by 64-bit processes. This was the reason my code always threw an exception. So the 64bit-processes were not listed.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are accessing obsolete fields?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569609

Comment: That has nothing to do with his question.